# How to Convert (timestamp, value) array to timeseries

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, time-series

I have a rather straightforward problem I'd like to solve with more efficiency than I'm currently getting.

I have a bunch of data coming in as a set of monitoring metrics.  Input data is structured as an array of tuples. Each tuple is (timestamp, value).  Timestamps are integer epoch seconds, and values are normal floating point numbers.  Example:

```
inArr = [ (1388435242, 12.3), (1388435262, 11.1), (1388435281, 12.8), ... ]
```

The timestamps are not always the same number of seconds apart, but it's usually close.  Sometimes we get duplicate numbers submitted, sometimes we miss datapoints, etc.

My current solution takes the timestamps and:

- finds the num seconds between each successive pair of timestamps;
- finds the median of these delays;
- creates an array of the correct size;
- presumes the first time period starts at half the median value before the first timestamp (putting the measurement in the middle of the time period);
- averages values that happen to go into the same time bucket;
- adds data to this array according to the correct (timestamp - starttime)/median element.
- if there's no value for a time range, I obviously output a None value.

Output data has to be in the format:

```
outArr = [ (startTime, timeStep, numVals), [ val1, val2, val3, val4, ... ] ]
```

I suspect this is a solved problem with Python Pandas http://pandas.pydata.org/  (or Numpy / SciPy).

Yes, my solution works, but when I'm operating on 60K datapoints it can take a tenth of a second (or more) to run.  This is troublesome when I'm trying to work on **large** numbers of sets of data.

So, I'm looking for a solution that might run faster than my pure-Python version.  I guess I'm presuming (based on a couple of previous conversations with an Argonne National Labs guy) that SciPy and Numpy are (clearing-throat) "somewhat faster" at array operations.  I've looked briefly (an hour or so) at the Pandas code but it looks cumbersome to do this set of operations.  Am I incorrect?

-- **Edit to show expected output** --

The median time between datapoints is 20 seconds, half that is 10 seconds.  To make sure we put the lines well between the timestamps, we make the start time 10 seconds before the first datapoint.  If we just make the start time the first timestamp, it's a lot more likely that we'll get 2 timestamps in one interval.

So, 1388435242 - 10 = 1388435232.  The timestep is the median, 20 seconds.  The numvals here is 3.

```
outArr = [ (1388435232, 20, 3), [ 12.3, 11.1, 12.8 ] )
```

This is the format that Graphite expects when we're graphing the output; it's not my invention.  It seems common, though, to have timeseries data be in this format - a starttime, interval, and then an array of values.

Comment: Have you tried using Numpy?

Comment: Numpy has numpy.median, this is good, I could use that.  But that's a small part of the problem.  Pandas might have a general solution for this, but there's a lot to Pandas and I'm an ub3r-n00b with it.

Comment: Yes, pandas can do all of those (and numpy too, but not nearly as easy). But your question is too broad to be addressed in  full detail. To be ontopic, You'd better try yourself, then search google and this site, and come with concrete problems if needed.

Comment: Not necessary to be off by 10 seconds like I suggest, just decided to do that in my code.  Mostly I'm concerned with getting the start, timestep, and bucketed array of values.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sketch

Create your input series

```
In [24]: x = zip(pd.date_range('20130101',periods=1000000,freq='s').asi8/1000000000,np.random.randn(1000000))

In [49]: x[0]
Out[49]: (1356998400, 1.2809949462375376)
```

Create the frame

```
In [25]: df = DataFrame(x,columns=['time','value'])
```

Make the dates a bit random (to simulate some data)

```
In [26]: df['time1'] = df['time'] + np.random.randint(0,10,size=1000000)
```

Convert the epoch seconds to datetime64[ns] dtype

```
In [29]: df['time2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time1'],unit='s')
```

Difference the series (to create timedeltas)

```
In [32]: df['diff'] = df['time2'].diff()
```

Looks like this

```
In [50]: df
Out[50]: 
          time     value       time1               time2      diff
0   1356998400 -0.269644  1356998405 2013-01-01 00:00:05       NaT
1   1356998401 -0.924337  1356998401 2013-01-01 00:00:01 -00:00:04
2   1356998402  0.952466  1356998410 2013-01-01 00:00:10  00:00:09
3   1356998403  0.604783  1356998411 2013-01-01 00:00:11  00:00:01
4   1356998404  0.140927  1356998407 2013-01-01 00:00:07 -00:00:04
5   1356998405 -0.083861  1356998414 2013-01-01 00:00:14  00:00:07
6   1356998406  1.287110  1356998412 2013-01-01 00:00:12 -00:00:02
7   1356998407  0.539957  1356998414 2013-01-01 00:00:14  00:00:02
8   1356998408  0.337780  1356998412 2013-01-01 00:00:12 -00:00:02
9   1356998409 -0.368456  1356998410 2013-01-01 00:00:10 -00:00:02
10  1356998410 -0.355176  1356998414 2013-01-01 00:00:14  00:00:04
11  1356998411 -2.912447  1356998417 2013-01-01 00:00:17  00:00:03
12  1356998412 -0.003209  1356998418 2013-01-01 00:00:18  00:00:01
13  1356998413  0.122424  1356998414 2013-01-01 00:00:14 -00:00:04
14  1356998414  0.121545  1356998421 2013-01-01 00:00:21  00:00:07
15  1356998415 -0.838947  1356998417 2013-01-01 00:00:17 -00:00:04
16  1356998416  0.329681  1356998419 2013-01-01 00:00:19  00:00:02
17  1356998417 -1.071963  1356998418 2013-01-01 00:00:18 -00:00:01
18  1356998418  1.090762  1356998424 2013-01-01 00:00:24  00:00:06
19  1356998419  1.740093  1356998428 2013-01-01 00:00:28  00:00:04
20  1356998420  1.480837  1356998428 2013-01-01 00:00:28  00:00:00
21  1356998421  0.118806  1356998427 2013-01-01 00:00:27 -00:00:01
22  1356998422 -0.935749  1356998427 2013-01-01 00:00:27  00:00:00
```

Calc median

```
In [34]: df['diff'].median()
Out[34]: 
0   00:00:01
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Calc mean

```
In [35]: df['diff'].mean()
Out[35]: 
0   00:00:00.999996
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Should get you started

Comment: first, why not `df['diff'] = df['time2'].diff()`? second, why preserve old data, i.e. introduce those time1, time2, and not simply overwrite `df['time']`?

Comment: @alko yep ...``diff`` is better hear; I was trying to 'illustrate' so didn't overwrite the columns

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your `inArr` to a pandas Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(inArr, columns=['time', 'value'])
```

- *num seconds between each successive pair of timestamps:* `df['time'].diff()`
- *median delay*: `df['time'].diff().median()`
- *creates an array of the correct size* (I think that's taken care of?)
- *presumes the first time period starts at half the median value before the first timestamp (putting the measurement in the middle of the time period)*; I don't know what you mean here
- averages values that happen to go into the same time bucket

For several of these problems it may make since to convert your seconds to `datetime` and set it as the index:

```
In [39]: df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')
In [41]: df = df.set_index('time')

In [42]: df
Out[42]: 
                     value
time                      
2013-12-30 20:27:22   12.3
2013-12-30 20:27:42   11.1
2013-12-30 20:28:01   12.8
```

Then to handle multiple values in the same time, use `groupby`.

```
In [49]: df.groupby(level='time').mean()
Out[49]: 
                     value
time                      
2013-12-30 20:27:22   12.3
2013-12-30 20:27:42   11.1
2013-12-30 20:28:01   12.8
```

It's the same since there aren't any dupes.

Not sure what you mean about the last two.

And your desired output seems to contradict what you wanted earlier. You values with the same timestamp should be averaged, and now you want them all? Maybe clear that up a bit.